# order by find_in_set(), and_then, and_then

Tags: mysql

This mysql query doesn't seem to work for me:

```
select *
from myTable
order by
  find_in_set( category, "First, Second" ),
  sortby,
  title;
```

Apparently you can't order beyond the find_in_set function?

Is there a way around this?  Am I missing something?

Thanks for your reply.

Edit:

This is the exact query being run:

```
select
  uid,
  category,
  title,
  summary,
  image_url,
  link_url,
  link_text
from links_and_documents
where link_url != ''
  and status=1
order by
  find_in_set( category, "Test_Category_Two,Test_Category_One" ),
  sortby,
  title;
```

It returns all the items you would expect but orders them by sortby and completely ignores the find_in_set function.

If I leave `,sortby,title` off the end of the query it sorts items by the find_in_set function.:

```
select
  uid,
  category,
  title,
  summary,
  image_url,
  link_url,
  link_text
from links_and_documents
where link_url != ''
  and status=1
order by
  find_in_set( category, "Test_Category_Two,Test_Category_One" );
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `links_and_documents` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `dateadded` varchar(19) NOT NULL default '',
  `dateupdated` varchar(19) NOT NULL default '',
  `uid` varchar(16) NOT NULL default '',
  `clientuid` varchar(16) NOT NULL default '',
  `status` char(1) NOT NULL default '1',
  `sortby` varchar(16) NOT NULL default '',
  `category` text NOT NULL,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `information` text NOT NULL,
  `summary` text NOT NULL,
  `services` text NOT NULL,
  `link_url` text NOT NULL,
  `link_text` text NOT NULL,
  `document_url` text NOT NULL,
  `document_text` text NOT NULL,
  `image_url` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `category` (`status`,`category`(30))
)
```

I receive no errors.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Moveover order is a reserved words. You have to put that field within backticks or rename it.

Comment: Sorry, order is not actually used in the query, was just making an example.  I'll reword the questions

Comment: Please post an example with some records and the expected result.

Comment: Are you getting any errors ? Please show your table structure or some table datas.

Comment: I posted the table structure.  I'm not getting any errors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was running into the same problem from several months:

```
order by find_in_set( category, "First, Second" )
```

use to work sometimes and sometimes NOT.
Today I read a lot and the next change solved my problem:

```
ORDER BY FIELD( category, 'First', 'Second' )
```

Hope it's not too late to help you.

Comment: After reading your answer I changed `find_in_set` with `FIELD`

Answer (score 5):

You should not keep spaces in

```
order by find_in_set( category, "First, Second, Third, Fourth" )
```

should be

```
order by find_in_set(category,"First,Second,Third,Fourth" )
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing the sorting for multiple columns in mysql, You have to specify the sorting order as mentioned in this below url,

[Mysql Order By Multiple Columns](http://www.develobert.info/2008/03/mysql-order-by-multiple-columns.html)

[Mysql Sorting Rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html)

Comment: I changed the example to say sortby instead of order.  The actual query does not use that.

Comment: As per your examples i changed the order by to read: 'order by find_in_set( category, "Test_Category_Two,Test_Category_One" ) ASC,sortby ASC'.  Unfortunately it did not have the desired effect.